# Settings up remote interpretor in pycharm for docker

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, tensorflow

I'm using **PyCharm community editor** 5.0.3.I. I want to run my **Tensorflow python** project on **docker** running on **windows**. As per comment community edition doesn't support remote interpretor. What's the possible way to excepting using Enterprise edition of PyCharm?

Comment: The Community edition does not support remote interpreter.